# Segment violation (`core 'generated) error in c program

Tags: c

I'm currently working in a c program that calculates the pi value using Leibniz summation, but I'm getting the error "segment violation (`core 'generated)" in the console once the program is executed. Also I've checked similar questions but I'm still unable to fit that info into my problem. This is the code I have:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

double calPi(int x);


double calPi(int x)
{
    double sum;
    int i;

    sum=0.0;

    for (i=0; i<=x; i++)
    {
        if ((i=2)||((i%2)==0))
        {
            sum=sum+(1/(2*i+1));
        }
        else sum=sum-(1/(2*i+1));
    }

return 4*sum;
}


int main(void)

{
    int x;
    double PI;

    printf("Enter the number of terms you want to calculate");
    scanf("%i",x);

    PI=calPi(x);

    printf("Pi value is: %f", PI);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any hint, help or correction.

Comment: `if ((i=2)||((i%2)==0))` causes infinite recursion.

Comment: If you had written if(2=i || (i%2) ==0), you would not need to ask this question.

Comment: @machine_1, yes, I still would have to ask this question because  was not the cause of the error, but thanks for the annotation.

Comment: The Liebniz summation starts with 1.0, not 0.0

Comment: regarding lines like: `else sum=sum-(1/(2*i+1));`  please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  The indicated line has two statements:  `else` and `sum=sum-(1/(2*i+1));`.  Such 'globbing' of statements makes the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%i",x);`  Always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  I.E. `if( scanf("%i",x) != 1 ) { // handle error }`  Note the `scanf()` family of functions return the number of successful 'input format' conversions

Comment: OT: regarding: `system("pause");`  this is not portable.  Suggest:  `int ch;  while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n' );  getchar();`

Comment: regarding: `if ((i=2)||((i%2)==0))`  This assigns 2 to the variable 'i'  So, 1) the body of the `if()` statement will always be entered.  2) depending on the value of 'x' this will either loop once or loop forever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
scanf("%i", x);
```

Should be

```
scanf("%i", &x);
```

You need to take the address of x, otherwise just using x , will be treated as a pointer pointing to who knows what.  Make sure you compile with warnings on, as your compiler should warn you about stuff like that.  My compiler complains with

"format string '%i' requires an argument of type 'int *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int'"

Comment: I was using the terminal as compiler so I was  receiving just a couple warnings not too clear about my mistakes, thank you so much for a clear answer and the explanation,